# ARCGIS: open feature into TOC

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

I'm trying to open 1000 maps automated with python script and export one by one.

Can some tell me how to open them to the TOC with the python script instead of doing by hand.
Also how do I change the visibility with python instead of doing by hand.

cheers
eactor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

part one is done with:

```
addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"C:/example.lyr")
```

part two you only open the ones you would like to see and remove the other ones:

```
arcpy.Delete_management(layername)
```

note: layername does not have to be the same as the lyr file name! It is the name which occurs in the TOC.